# Problemas en mi management studio para reconocer conversión de varchar a fecha

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-management

Mi caso es el siguiente :
Yo corro un select donde convierto un varchar a fecha , que en mi PC bota un mensaje de error , sin embargo en otra pc de otra persona corre con normalidad.Tengo ese problema desde hace tiempo .Si alguien le ha pasado porfi ayuda.

```
select CONVERT(DATE,fecha_alta,103)
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

a veces quiero hacer un DATEIFF o otro tipo de comparacion de fechas y se me complica porque no se convierte el varchar a fecha.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a comenzar por poner las cosas en orden:

- Este problema no es del management studio, que no es más que un cliente de la base de datos. Donde corre el script es en el motor de la base de datos, y este motor está respondiendo con el error, porque no logra convertir al menos un dato almacenado en la tabla subyacente a la consulta.
- La otra persona que donde corre con normalidad, o bien no está conectada al mismo servidor de base de datos y tirando exactamente de la misma tabla, o tiene una consulta diferente, quizás con alguna condición que hace que se devuelva un conjunto diferente de filas y, casualmente, en esas filas no viene el lo los datos problemáticos que tu si estas recuperando.

En resumen, **el problema está en los datos**.

Para ver dónde está el error, habría que ver la información que está almacenada en el campo `fecha_alta`. Lo que ocurre es que hay una o más filas donde el valor almacenado en el campo `fecha_alta` no es una fecha válida en el formato 103, que es `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Esa inspección te toca hacerla a ti. Lo que yo voy a hacer es dejarte tres un ejemplos, que puedes ejecutar en tu motor de base de datos (a través del *management studio*) para que puedas observar el problema desde una perspectiva adecuada.

Primero, una consulta simple que si funciona:

```
select convert(date, '01/01/2021', 103)
```

Y dos consultas simples que te van a dar el mismo error que estás observando:

```
select convert(date, '31/02/2021', 103)
select convert(date, 'No soy fecha', 103)
```

La primera fila tiene una fecha que no existe en el calendario y la segunda ni siquiera tiene una fecha. Ambas producen el error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Ahora, creo *al vuelo* una tabla `X` que tiene dos campos (`id` y `fecha_alta`), esta última algunas con filas con datos válidos y una con un dato inválido. Por esta razón genera el mismo error:

```
with
X as (
select *
  from (values (1, '01/01/2021')
             , (2, '28/02/2021')
             , (3, '29/02/2021')
             , (4, '01/03/2021')
       ) q1 (id, fecha_alta)
)
select id, fecha_alta, convert(date, fecha_alta, 103)
  from X
 order by id;
```

No solo provoca el mismo error sino que devuelve un conjunto *incompleto* de resultados:

```
id          fecha_alta 
----------- ---------- ----------
1           01/01/2021 2021-01-01
2           28/02/2021 2021-02-28
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


Completion time: 2021-04-15T14:15:03.2705876-06:00
```

Dado que tengo la consulta ordenada por `id`, puedo deducir que es la fila con el ID 3 la que es problemática. Al ver el conjunto de datos, efectivamente `'29/02/2021'` no es una fecha válida (el 2021 no es bisiesto).

La moraleja de esto, para mi, es:

### Es mejor SIEMPRE almacenar las fechas en campos de un tipo de datos especializado, como `date`, `datetime`, etc.

Las conversiones van a ser siempre frágiles, además de menos eficientes.

Si quieres evitar problemas de conversión y obtener resultados, utiliza la función [`try_convert()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql), recibe los mismos parámetros que `convert()`, pero no lanza un error al no lograr convertir, sino que devuelve `null`, por ejemplo, sustituyendo la función en la última consulta del ejemplo:

```
with
X as (
select *
  from (values (1, '01/01/2021')
             , (2, '28/02/2021')
             , (3, '29/02/2021')
             , (4, '01/03/2021')
       ) q1 (id, fecha_alta)
)
select id, fecha_alta, try_convert(date, fecha_alta, 103)
  from X
 order by id;
```

obtenemos como resultado:

```
id          fecha_alta 
----------- ---------- ----------
1           01/01/2021 2021-01-01
2           28/02/2021 2021-02-28
3           29/02/2021 NULL
4           01/03/2021 2021-03-01

(4 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-04-15T14:22:14.6647120-06:00
```

Finalmente, si quieres ver todas las filas que tienen datos incorrectos, puedes valerte de esta función y lanzar una sentencia como la siguiente:

```
select id, fecha_alta
  from X
 where try_convert(date, fecha_alta, 103) is null
 order by id;
```